# Maven not compiling my source files

Tags: maven, war, activiti

I have a Maven project that I imported from a git repository:

https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti.git
tag 5.12

I imported one maven project (Explorer2) and it packages just fine and the war deploys to the tomcat server just fine. The project did not import into Eclipse with the source files. I do have the source files and have added them in the scr folder. The file I changed (as a test) is found here:

src > org > activiti > explorer > demo > DemoDataGenerator.java

I also added a test class here:

src > com > test > Test.java

Neither of these compile. I have tried "package" and "compile" on the "Run as" menu and "build project".

How do I set this up to compile the source files?

Comment: The project has a unique layout, to say the least. Your going to have to add your classes to one of the existing modules, or create a new one of your own.

Comment: Please look at the [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).